# Kotlin documentation doesn't support tags like '<p>' well

Tags: android, javadoc, kotlin, kdoc

I'm writing doc comments to describe a method.

```css
   /**
     * <p>necessary
     * <p>setType is to set the PendingIntend's request code</p>
     */
```

But it won't show the paragraphs. If I don't use the `<p>`, all the documentation is in a line without any break.
It works in Java class but when it comes to Kotlin, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I think you are talking about doc comments, not about annotations. Please edit the question (its name)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As said in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup), KDoc (equivalent of Java’s JavaDoc in Kotlin) utilizes regular [Markdown syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/) for inline markup instead of HTML tags.

In Markdown, paragraphs are just split by an empty line, like this:

```
/**
 * necessary
 *
 * setType is to set the PendingIntend's request code
 */
```

Also, please see [this example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#kdoc-syntax) in the Kotlin reference.